# Passing in multiple arguements to apply/sapply sytnax

Tags: r, apply, sapply

Newb here - unable to figure out some basic syntax and given the common-ness of the words google isnt helping....

```
mtcars$testcol = 'testing'
imgood = sapply(mtcars, IQR, na.rm=T) #works ok... helpme =
sapply(mtcars, quantile c(.3,.9, .95, na.rm=TRUE)  #don't know how to
```

Then what I would like to do is just

```
mtcars$mynewcolumn = imgood....etc
```

pass in parameters with sapply/apply...

Also I have been looking at summarise_each, summarise_all with dplyr::
Is there a way this would work here?

Comment: How about ```sapply(mtcars, function(x) {
    quantile(x,c(.3,.9, .95, na.rm=TRUE))
})```?

Comment: This is a typo.  You missed a comma `sapply(mtcars, quantile, c(.3,.9, .95, na.rm=TRUE))`

Comment: This works until I add in a non-numeric column like I did above.    I tried something like    ----sapply(mtcars, function(x) {ifelse(is.numeric(x), quantile(x,c(.3,.9, na.rm=TRUE)),'xxx') })   ---- but then I don't get output for multipel values

Comment: Then only run it on the numeric columns; it doesn't make sense to compute IQR for non-numeric columns, anyway. Or are we missing something? It may help to show us what you're starting with and what you want to end with, and then after that tell us what you've tried.

Comment: @Aaron is right. There is no point in getting a percentile of a character vector. Hence, the name of the function ***quantile***.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to just having to avoid doing all the splitting/prep work where it would just pass over non-numeric data.  So I would just see NA if it was a factor or character ro something

Comment: But where you're really losing us is what you want to do with the result. Somehow you want to add a new column with the results, but it won't have the right dimensions, even if everything is numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `quantile` was not designed to return a vector of NA's or a single NA. To get this to happen you could write an enclosing function that would act the way you were hoping:

```
my_quantile <- function(x, ...) if ( is.numeric(x) ) {quantile(x,...)} else {
                                                 z <- list(...)[[1]]; rep(NA,length(z))}

> sapply(mtcars, my_quantile, c(.3,.9, .95), na.rm=TRUE)
      mpg cyl   disp     hp   drat      wt    qsec vs am gear carb testcol
30% 15.98   4 142.06 106.20 3.1500 2.77300 17.0200  0  0    3  2.0      NA
90% 30.09   8 396.00 243.50 4.2090 4.04750 19.9900  1  1    5  4.0      NA
95% 31.30   8 449.00 253.55 4.3145 5.29275 20.1045  1  1    5  4.9      NA
```

It's probably not the first function you would write, since it requires extracting the second argument passed to quantile to repeat NA's the number of times to match the other quantiles which in turn allows `sapply` to retrun a matrix rather than a list. It's also going to be a bit fragile, since you are not naming your arguments. If `probs` had been named then it might not have been first, so it might have been better to check to see whether `match.args` could find a `probs` argument, and then, if that failed, to use the first argument in the `...`-argument-list.